# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' in dockerised Django app using docker-compose

Tags: python, mysql, django, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to build a Dockerized Django application with a MySQl database, but am unable to connect to the database when running `docker-compose up`

My `Dockerfile`  is:

```bash
# Use the official Python image as the base image
FROM python:3.10

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the requirements file and install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["sh", "-c", "python manage.py migrate"]

# Copy the project files into the container
COPY . /app/
```

And `docker-compose.yml` looks like:

```bash
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE='model_db'
      - MYSQL_USER='root'
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD='password'
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='password'
    volumes:
      - /tmp/app/mysqld:/var/run/mysqld
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - .env
```

I'm using a `.env` file to define environment variables, and it is:

```bash
MYSQL_DATABASE=model_db
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
MYSQL_HOST=db
```

These are then loaded to the app `settings.py` like this:

```py
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
env = environ.Env()

if READ_DOT_ENV_FILE := env.bool("DJANGO_READ_DOT_ENV_FILE", default=True):
    # OS environment variables take precedence over variables from .env
    env.read_env(env_file=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.env'))

MYSQL_DATABASE = env('MYSQL_DATABASE', default=None)
MYSQL_USER = env('MYSQL_USER', default=None)
MYSQL_PASSWORD = env('MYSQL_PASSWORD', default=None)
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD = env('MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD',default=None)
MYSQL_HOST = env('MYSQL_HOST', default=None)

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'MYSQL_DATABASE': MYSQL_DATABASE,
        'USER': MYSQL_USER,                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': MYSQL_PASSWORD,                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD': MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD,
        'HOST': MYSQL_HOST,
        'PORT': 3306,
    },
}
```

When I run `docker-compose up` it errors out with `_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db:3306' (99)`

Any suggestions?

Comment: i think because you set the `HOST` to localhost. Just remove it from the mysql container config in the compose file and specify the host in your `.env` with `db` (which is the name you gave the service in your `docker-compose`

Comment: "*`MYSQL_HOST=localhost`*" - `localhost` refers to the container itself. Within the `web`-container, there is on process listening on port `3306`. If we want to communicate with the `db`-container, we reference it by the container name (`db`).

Comment: Just replace `MYSQL_HOST=localhost` to `MYSQL_HOST=db` in the `.env` Docker will automatically get Internal IP of db container.

Comment: Thanks, but now this throws the error: `Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db:3306' (111)`

Comment: I don't know that it's helpful, but the db container outputs indicate it's ready for connections: `X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock`  `[Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.1.0'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.`

Comment: Can you update the Question with the changes you made to the `docker-compose` file and also to the `.env` file?

Comment: That plugin is unrelated to your actual DB being available https://stackoverflow.com/a/56720792/6336357. Did you set a bind address in the mysql config?

Comment: @Kevin That's done now.

Comment: @ColeRobertson whats the purpose to map the mysqld?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the issues(s), which were several.

1. The host was wrong. Following several comments, I changed `"MYSQL_HOST=localhost"` to `"MYSQL_HOST=db"`, i.e. the container name.
2. The `web` container was starting before the database server was ready, causing the connection error, because `depends_on` will only wait for a container to be up, not actually fully initialised. Instituting a health_check, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567475/docker-compose-check-if-mysql-connection-is-ready) and [this](https://www.atatus.com/blog/health-check-command-in-docker/#parameters-for-health-check) solved the issue.
3. `python3 manage.py migrate` would not work unless I created a `DATABASE_URL` variable, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75276228/how-to-fix-django-db-utils-operationalerror-1046-no-database-selected), where `DATABASE_URL == mysql://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<db_name>` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33854118/how-do-i-specify-the-password-in-the-mysql-connection-url))

The final working `Dockerfile`, `docker-compose.yml`, `settings.py` and `.env` files were:

#### Dockerfile

```bash
# Use the official Python image as the base image
FROM python:3.10

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the requirements file and install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the project files into the container
COPY . /app/
```

#### .env

```bash
MYSQL_DATABASE=modeldb
MYSQL_USER=mysql
MYSQL_PASSWORD=mypass
MYSQL_HOST=db
DATABASE_URL=mysql://mysql:mypass@db:3306/modeldb
```

#### settings.py

```py
MYSQL_DATABASE = env('MYSQL_DATABASE', default=None)
MYSQL_USER = env('MYSQL_USER', default=None)
MYSQL_PASSWORD = env('MYSQL_PASSWORD', default=None)
MYSQL_HOST = env('MYSQL_HOST', default=None)
DATABASE_URL = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL', '')

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'MYSQL_DATABASE': MYSQL_DATABASE,
        'USER': MYSQL_USER,                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': MYSQL_PASSWORD,                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': MYSQL_HOST,
        'PORT': 3306,
    },
}

if DATABASE_URL:
    import dj_database_url
    DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(default=DATABASE_URL)
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```bash
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'modeldb'
      MYSQL_USER: 'mysql'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'test'
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
    volumes:
      - ./db_django:/var/lib/mysql
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"] # Command to check health.
      interval: 10s # Interval between health checks.
      timeout: 10s # Timeout for each health checking.
      retries: 20 # How many times retries.
      start_period: 30s # Warm up wait period
  web:
    build: .
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py collectstatic --noinput &&
             python manage.py migrate &&
             python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    env_file:
      - .env
```

Answer (score 2):

There some steps i think you should do:

1. You don't need to expose the mysql port because the containers are in the same network
2. You don't need `CMD` in your Dockerfile. Just do this in your command directive in your docker-compose:

```
command: python3 manage.py migrate && python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Other things seems right.

Hope it helps !